# Compromise between id and key referencing

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database, jsonb

I have the following tables for keeping a product with its attributes:

**Attributes**

```
id name        
1  color       
2  material
```

**Attribute values**

```
id attribute_id value    
  1     1       black    
  2     2       plastic
```

**Products**

```
id  name     attributes
 1  Laptop   {1:"1",2:"2"}
```

Attribute in the Products table is referenced by id (1). But it could also be referenced by attribute name:

```
{"color":"black"}
```

Though it breaks data integrity it allows to upload products with attributes which are not in a DB yet. Those could be added later, and then products could be filtered by them.
I ask for an advice on how to use the benefits of both approaches? I want to reference the existing attributes by ids or names, and reference all others by names in the Products table.

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) already asked here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224603

Comment: See the link from my first comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu